# How to set row level rendering in JSF <h:datatable>

Tags: jsf, rendering, facelets

How can i set row level rendering in datatable JSF.

```
 <h:dataTable  styleClass="tablesub" border="0"  value="#{historyQuestBean.answerMasterList[row].inputTextKeySet}" var="option">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{option.sectionShortName}:"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{option.type}:"/>
        </h:column>
 </h:dataTable>
```

I want to render only those rows who have status true.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier and Simplest thing is to pass the list of values with `status = true`

In `<h:datatable>` you can give a style class within `rowClasses` say `renderer` and in that class specify a condition like `display:#{option.status==true}?'block':'none'`. This will evaluate the EL and accordingly place the style of that `<tr\>` to display or not.

Another option is to use [`<ui:repeat>`](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-repeat-tag-example/) instead of `<h:datatable>`, Here you can place rendered condition for the `<tr>`.